# Graylog causes an exception - Message is invalid: short-message not set

Tags: php, laravel, graylog

**Tools & env: php 8.0, laravel 9, docker alpine 3.15, [gelf logger package](https://github.com/hedii/laravel-gelf-logger)**

I'm trying to set up graylog for my laravel project. Everything looks ok, but every time it does write logs, it actually writes 2 logs -> the log itself and this error message:

```
local.ERROR: Message is invalid: short-message not set {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Message is invalid: short-message not set at /var/www/vendor/graylog2/gelf-php/src/Gelf/Publisher.php:72)
```

[image: Print screen from graylog]

I could not find out what causes the error. I assume that my configuration could be wrong.

`config/logging.php`

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['gelf'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],

   .....

'gelf' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'via' => \Hedii\LaravelGelfLogger\GelfLoggerFactory::class,
        'processors' => [
            \Hedii\LaravelGelfLogger\Processors\NullStringProcessor::class,
            \Hedii\LaravelGelfLogger\Processors\RenameIdFieldProcessor::class,
        ],
        'level' => 'debug',
        'name' => 'my-custom-name',
        'system_name' => null,
        'transport' => 'tcp',
        'host' => env('GRAYLOG_HOST_TCP', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('GRAYLOG_PORT', 12201),
        'path' => null,
        'ssl' => false,
        'ssl_options' => [
            'verify_peer' => true,
            'ca_file' => null,
            'ciphers' => null,
            'allow_self_signed' => false,
        ],
        'max_length' => null,
        'context_prefix' => null,
        'extra_prefix' => null,
        'ignore_error' => true,
    ],
```

`.env`

```
GRAYLOG_HOST_TCP=192.168.55.20
GRAYLOG_HOST=http://127.0.0.1
GRAYLOG_PORT=5555
GRAYLOG_API_PORT=9999
GRAYLOG_VOLUME=/volume
GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=somepasswordpepper
# The value is admin.
GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=5345345345dfgdfgdfgf
```

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2
    volumes:
      - ${GRAYLOG_VOLUME}/mongodb:/data/db
    networks:
      - proxy
  # Elasticsearch required for graylog.
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:7.10.2
    volumes:
      - ${GRAYLOG_VOLUME}/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - http.host=0.0.0.0
      - transport.host=localhost
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1g
    networks:
      - proxy

  graylog:
    image: graylog/graylog:4.2
    environment:
      # CHANGE ME (must be at least 16 characters)!
      - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=${GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET}
      # Password: admin
      - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=${GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2}
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=${GRAYLOG_HOST}:${GRAYLOG_API_PORT}/
    entrypoint: /usr/bin/tini -- wait-for-it elasticsearch:9200 --  /docker-entrypoint.sh
    networks:
      proxy:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.55.20
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      # Graylog web interface and REST API
      - "${GRAYLOG_API_PORT}:9000"
      # Syslog TCP
      - "1514:1514"
      # Syslog UDP
      - "1514:1514/udp"
      # GELF TCP
      - "12201:12201"
      # GELF UDP
      - "12201:12201/udp"
      # Graylog
      - "${GRAYLOG_PORT}:5555"
      - "${GRAYLOG_PORT}:5555/udp"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Michael Wendel asks: *"Did you ever solve this? I'm getting the same error"*

Comment: nope, haven't resolved it